# How to create custom SEO-friendly URLs in OpenCart?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, opencart

I would like http://example.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart to be display as http://example.com/cart. A few days ago I found an answer in StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/q/7578055/1236271). And I made the necessary changes in the seo_url file and also updated the database but still, it's not working for me. Is there any mistake with my seo_url file? This is my seo_url.php file.

```
<?php

class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
public function index() {
    // Add rewrite to url class
    if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
        $this->url->addRewrite($this);
    }
    // Decode URL
    if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
        $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

            if ($query->num_rows) {
                $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);                  

                if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                    $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                }                   

                if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                    if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                        $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                    } else {
                        $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                    }
                }               

                if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                    $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                }               

                if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                    $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                }
            } else {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   
            }
        }           

        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/product';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
        }
        else {
                            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->get['_route_']) . "'");
            if ($query->num_rows) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];
            }
       }
        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
        }
    }
}



public function rewrite($link) {

    if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {

        $url_data = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));



        $url = ''; 



        $data = array();



        parse_str($url_data['query'], $data);



        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            if (isset($data['route'])) {

                if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/product' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {

                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");



                    if ($query->num_rows) {

                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];



                        unset($data[$key]);

                    }                   

                } elseif ($key == 'path') {

                    $categories = explode('_', $value);



                    foreach ($categories as $category) {

                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");



                        if ($query->num_rows) {

                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        }                           

                    }



                    unset($data[$key]);

                }

                else {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['route']) . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
               }


            }

        }



        if ($url) {

            unset($data['route']);



            $query = '';



            if ($data) {

                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                    $query .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;

                }



                if ($query) {

                    $query = '?' . trim($query, '&');

                }

            }



            return $url_data['scheme'] . '://' . $url_data['host'] . (isset($url_data['port']) ? ':' . $url_data['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_data['path']) . $url . $query;

        } else {

            return $link;

        }

    } else {

        return $link;

    }       

}   

}

?>
```

Comment: Is anyone there to solve this problem or to give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Simple question, did you turn on the Rewrite module or do you have the rewrite module enabled on your hosting solution ?

And did you create the good .htaccess to make all of this work ?

Comment: It's enabled and it's working for all others also. but how can I create custom urls?