# Remove index.php?route=common/home from OpenCart

Tags: php, seo, opencart

I currently have `User SEO URL's` set to Yes in OpenCart Admin.

`System -> Settings -> Store -> Server -> User SEO URL's`

So far, all tags and SEO links are working; the command has done the desired effect.

However for the homepage and a few other links; how do I remove:

> index.php?route=common/home

From the URL? Do I have to literally do a find and replace in the hardcode PHP files and risk upgrades or is there another way?

(without bloating performance i.e no poor amateur tools such as vQmod)

Comment: As far as I know 100% hard-code - What is worse is if the OpenCart Enviroment is run on Nginx so you need to write many manual functions - and also it is not as easy as finding and replacing that /common/home - much more functions around itself! Repped.. as I want answer too

Comment: Have you tried removing with `htaccess`?

Comment: @PLB you cannot do this as I am using Nginx and aside from that .htaccess only redirects or rewrites - you still have to remove the index.php?route= in the code.

Comment: The only way I found to do it was to [modify the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578055/how-can-i-create-custom-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart)

Comment: You can check my answer. Solved on 1.5.5.1

Comment: all the answers working but my opinion is to change this url type through database query

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To simply remove that, you can do a basic replace in `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`

Find:

```
return $link;
```

**Before** it on a new line put:

```
$link = str_replace('index.php?route=common/home', '', $link);
```

Edit by TheBlackBenzKid: If you want full SEO just use this line instead of the above:

```
$link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);
```

Also make sure SEO URLs is turned on in the Admin panel of the store.

Comment: So would remove all `index.php?route=` as essentially that is what is needed.

Comment: Edit, I have added another solution above. Thanks for this.

Comment: What you've added will set the route sure, however this can have implications. For example, firstly you need to convert the new url back to the route when you link to it. Secondly what happens if a page has other parameters than just the route. Say you use the search page, you'll have `product/search&page=2&query=something` which is an invalid URL, so I would advise against what you've got above

Comment: I would have to create links and nginx url rewrites for all scenarios. This is fine as we have pretty much done all the parameters and query URLs. I did already know about this but a good point you raised.

Comment: This does not work with 1.5.5.1 anyone got the solution? vQmod does not work either. How annoying that the author has not put it in place.

Comment: You mean vQmod doesn't work with version 1.5.5.1? If so, I can assure you it does

Comment: @JayGilford I am saying the solutions above and the vQmod solution of this rewrite does not exist or work; 1.5.5.1 does not seem to be working

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - Solution was fairly trivial - see edit above

Comment: This still does not work for me :( I have done that and using 1.5.5.1

Comment: OK fixed. You need to make SEO URLs is on in the admin panel.

Comment: Correct, the class never even gets called if the seo url's are disabled

Comment: This is not a solution at all. This will mess up with the SEO URL translate inside OpenCart and the query sequence will become illegal, as someone pointed before. The solution is not inside `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php` but yes in `/system/libray/url.php`

Comment: @VictorSchröder Editing that file will affect the admin side as well as the catalog side. My solution is for the catalog side only and the reason why I didn't suggest the url class in the first place. Also since SEO URL's needs to be enabled to translate the URL's back into OC URL's, your solution point on it not being required to be enabled is of no relevance

Comment: Yes, it will remove the `index.php?route=common/home` in the admin too, but nothing breaks there and works perfectly, because the code handles to put the `?` in the right place. The query string is preserved in all cases, including the admin token. With the code I suggested we can get rid of the annoying `index.php?route=common/home` forever, and only it.

Comment: Another point is with the code suggested by @TheBlackBenzKid, links to pages that do not have SEO URLs field filled or does not have this field will break, even when SEO URLs **IS** enabled, which is a common case in the real world. The cart or checkout pages, for example, or a product or category with incomplete information.

Comment: I've tried implementing this solution, but there is something that bothers me. Implementing this mod will create two links pointing to my index page (home). `http://mydomain.tld/index.php?route=common/home` AND `http://mydomain.tld/`. Which is bad for SEO, I have now two links pointing to my index page.

Comment: Why not just `return str_replace...`?

Comment: @yckart you could I guess, its just if other code (such as vqmods) place code just before the `return $link` those wouldn't affect it

Comment: @Umair - clearly the 16 people that upvoted this question compared to your downvote disagree. I'm guessing you're not using OpenCart 1.5 or using a separate SEO mod

Comment: @JayGilford m using OC 2

Comment: @Umair right. This question was asked 2.5 years before OC2 was released

Comment: I suppose [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10902883/4094098) can also be used by vQmod in OC 2.x, no? In this case, by the way, maybe it can answer to [this question about rewriting for categories](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33238104/4094098)?

Comment: 8 years later and this problem still exist??? WHAT???

Answer (score 9):

I really like Victor Schröder's solution above for it's simplicity.  Thanks!  I created a vQmod based on his code mods in case it would be helpful to anyone.  here is the code:

```
<modification>

    <file name="system/library/url.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[$url .= 'index.php?route=' . $route;]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if ('common/home' == $route) {
                    if ($args) {
                        $url .= '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&'));
                    }
                } else {
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (isset($url_info['query'])) parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

Answer (score 8):

The previous "solutions" are wrong because they are attacking the SEO URL **translate**. What you want is to deal with the URL **generation** inside OpenCart.

Let's keep it simple. Go to `/system/library/url.php` and look at the `public function link`. Replace the function with this version:

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $connection = 'NONSSL') {
    if ('NONSSL' == $connection) {
        $url = $this->url;
    } else {
        $url = $this->ssl;  
    }

    if ('common/home' == $route) {
        if ($args) {
            $url .= '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&')); 
        }
    } else {
        $url .= 'index.php?route=' . $route;
        if ($args) {
            $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&')); 
        }
    }

    foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
        $url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Simple like that. I can't belive why this is not in OpenCart's core.

**EDIT:**

I run some tests and if the SEO URLs are enabled, it becomes necessary to make one single edit in the `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php` to avoid an "Undefined index" error.

Inside `public function rewrite`, replace this line:

```
parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);
```

With this one:

```
if (isset($url_info['query'])) parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);
```

Now it really works.

Comment: This will work with OR without SEO URLs enabled and will preserve the query string arguments

Comment: opencart 1.5.5.1.2 - I see `myshop/index.php?route` at url

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, what kind of OC version is that? Is it an official release? Are you sure that you have the SEO urls turned on? Anyway, I really recommend you to upgrade, because such an old version is not supported anymore and has a lot of security issues.

Comment: Hey Victor, thanks for this! I did everything to the letter but nothing happened. Does this work with 3.0?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 01. Enable USE SEO URL’s in your store server settings**

Go to the “System” and click on “Settings”. Locate the store you want to alter and click the “Edit” link on the right. Finally click the “Server” tab and set the SEO URL’s radio to “Yes” and save your settings.

Note: The keywords will not be created for you automatically. You must also have Apache mod_rewrite turned on. Most web hosts will have this on by default. Step 3 of this tutorial will explain how to add the keywords.

**Step 02. Change some content in your .htaccess file to make your homepage SEO URL Friendly**

Go to your host control panel and edit your .htaccess file. Sometimes this file is hidden in order to unhide it you can click on your web host control panel file manager and tick the show hidden files option followed by the “go” button.

Once you locate the .htaccess file change the following lines:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.yourwebsite.co.uk? [R=301,L]
```

If you do the step above your home page will change from something like this: http://yourwebsite.com/index.php?route=common/home to this: http://yourwebsite.com

**Step 03. Enter SEO Keywords for URL’s manually**
Finally, you need to enter SEO keywords for every page, information, product and category you want to have URL rewrite. You can find the field for the SEO Keywords under the Data tab when editing and creating items.

Once you have entered the SEO Keywords your URL’s will be working.

Once you have followed all these instructions you can begin to reap the benefits of higher rankings, increased traffic and more customers.

Comment: I think the whole point is to be able to do this automatically not manually every time you create a product/page.

Answer (score 2):

How about replacing a link in logo with `<?php echo $base; ?>`. It will make a link to base domain and will remove `index.php?route=common/home`.

Comment: It will remove that sure, but what about the rest of the index.php?route=common/home urls?

Comment: It is a good point. I like it and +1 but it is not a complete solution. I never knew about the `$base`

Comment: not complete solution.. clicking something in the nav bar also goes to index.php?blabla

Answer (score 2):

Jay's solution doesn't work for me, after editing I get blank screen. So I made a new one:

Put the line before:

```
return $link;
```

Instead of after:

```
public function rewrite($link) {
```

Comment: Interesting. What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the feedback

Comment: This does not work with 1.5.5.1 anyone got the solution? vQmod does not work either. How annoying that the author has not put it in place.

Comment: I will award the bounty here since this is the solution JayGilford used. Also make sure SEO URLs is turned on in the Admin Panel..

Comment: Works for me on my opencart development site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sir. I used that method for transforming route links into seo friendly with a little help of .htaccess

Comment: `Put the line before:

return $link;
Instead of after:

public function rewrite($link) {`  i do not get ... what are you trying to say ... please help

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm using 1.5.5.1 and no one answer on this question solved my problem.
However, combining the answers from [@Jay Gilford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711273/jay-gilford), [@TheBlackBenzKid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596952/theblackbenzkid) and [@rkaartikeyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707852/rkaartikeyan) I came up with a fully working solution.

Remember to enable seo urls as shown by [@TheBlackBenzKid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596952/theblackbenzkid).

An explanation can be found below the code.

```
[php]
class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }

        // Decode URL
        if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
            $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                    if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                            $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                        } else {
                            $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                        }
                    }   

                    if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                        $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                        $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                    }   
                } else {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   
                }
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
            }else {
                $this->request->get['route'] = $this->request->get['_route_'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function rewrite($link) {
        $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&', '&', $link));

        $url = ''; 

        $data = array();

        parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($data['route'])) {
                if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }                   
                } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                    $categories = explode('_', $value);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                        }                           
                    }

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($url) {
            unset($data['route']);

            $query = '';

            if ($data) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $query .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;
                }

                if ($query) {
                    $query = '?' . trim($query, '&');
                }
            }

            return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
        } else {
            $link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);
            return $link;
        }
    }   
}
```

Apparently, [@Jay Gilford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711273/jay-gilford) and [@TheBlackBenzKid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596952/theblackbenzkid) solve the issue of the urls being properly written on the page.

```
Line 113

$link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);
```

But it seems to break the urls since the Controller can't find the pages and therefore reverts to the error page.

```
Line 38 - 40

} else {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   
}
```

[@rkaartikeyen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707852/rkaartikeyan) solution solves this problem by setting the current route to the requested route

```
Line 51 - 53

else {
    $this->request->get['route'] = $this->request->get['_route_'];
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Also, I stopped using OC a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I came late but my solution could be useful for others (tested on Opencart 2.0.3.1):

Open your MySQL console and run this query (change YOURDATABASE with your db name):

```
INSERT INTO `YOURDATABASE`.`url_alias` (`url_alias_id`, `query`, `keyword`) VALUES (NULL, 'common/home', ' ');
```

How it works:

The trick consists in adding a WHITE SPACE (' ') for the column "keyword", if you insert an empty string ('') this workaround doesn't work and the url rewriter will return again index.php?route=common/home.

Comment: Working at `1.5.5.1.2`, but with space at `keyword` I have `%20` at the end of my url when clicking to logo so I removed the space.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simplest way to do it:

1- Go to `/system/library/url.php`

2- Locate `function link(`

3- Above `return $url;` put the following line:

```
$url = str_replace('index.php?route=common/home', '', $url);
```

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Yes, tested on Version 3.0.3.3

Comment: for me it either worked for 3.0.3.8

Answer (score 1):

## OpenCart 3.x

First of all in root folder of your website rename **htaccess.txt** into **.htaccess**.

Then go to ***System > Settings > Your store***. Edit. Open tab ***Server*** and set **Use SEO URLs** to ***Yes***.

Now open ***catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php***

Find `} elseif ($key == 'path') {`

Add before

```
} elseif ($key == 'route') {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($value) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
 
  if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
    unset($data[$key]);
  } else if ($data['route'] == "common/home") { 
    $url .= '/'; 
  }
```

Now `/index.php?route=common/home` becames `/`

And now you can although set SEO URLs in ***Design > SEO URL*** using constructions like **account/login** or **information/contact**.

Answer (score 0):

/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php

Open the file and replace the below code

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }

        // Decode URL
        if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
            $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

            foreach ($parts as $part) {

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                    if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                            $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                        } else {
                            $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                        }
                    }   

                    if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                        $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                        $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                    }   
                } else {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   
                }
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
            } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
            }else {
                $this->request->get['route'] = $this->request->get['_route_'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function rewrite($link) {
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $url_data = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));
            $url = ''; 

            $data = array();

            parse_str($url_data['query'], $data);
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                if (isset($data['route'])) {
                    if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                            unset($data[$key]);
                        }                   
                    } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                        $categories = explode('_', $value);

                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                            if ($query->num_rows) {
                                $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                            }                           
                        }

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }else {
                        $url .= '/'.$value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($url) {
                unset($data['route']);

                $query = '';

                if ($data) {
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        $query .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;
                    }

                    if ($query) {
                        $query = '?' . trim($query, '&');
                    }
                }

                return $url_data['scheme'] . '://' . $url_data['host'] . (isset($url_data['port']) ? ':' . $url_data['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_data['path']) . $url . $query;
            } else {
                return $link;
            }
        } else {
            return $link;
        }       
    }   
}
?>
```

*------------------* WHERE THE CHANGE *-------------------------*

The below Line i added in Public Function index() also Public Function rewrite.

```
else {
this->request->get['route'] = $this->request->get['_route_'];
}
```

index() function Perform like this

1. Get the query from htaccss "?*route*=$1" (Ex: the url look like site.com/shirts)
2. so the *route* is shirts
3. now the function check the "shirts" is found in url_alias table if its found then its make a get varible like index.php?categoryID=Value from url_alias Table.
4. Or else if there are no record in url_alias table for shirts, then its checks weather it is some other pages like information or manufacturer if its found it make a get variable Example index.php?route=information/information or index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info.
5. But its not check is it found in Layouts. So i added the Code in else block that set the *route* into get variable like this index.php?route=<*route*>
6. So in index() functions its works fine.
   Like Same i did in rewrite function.

Answer (score 0):

i got this http://www.antropy.co.uk/index.php/blog/one-quick-opencart-seo-tip-to-avoid-a-duplicate-home-page/ worked for me in removing the code for my homepage

Answer (score 0):

In file \system\library\response.php
add next line at the beginning of the public function output()

```
if (!defined('HTTP_CATALOG')) $this->output = str_replace(array('index.php?route=common/home', '?route=common/home'), '', $this->output);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Opencart 3, if you want to redirect all ugly urls, like

```
index.php?route=common/home
index.php?route=account/register
index.php?route=product/product&path=244&product_id=481
```

You need to add your pretty urls to `Admin -> Design -> SEO Urls` similar to

[image]

then do this: In `catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php`, in function `index`, after

```php
if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
   $this->url->addRewrite($this);
}
```

add this

```php
if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
    if (DOMAIN_ROOT . $this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'] != $this->rewrite(DOMAIN_ROOT . $this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $this->response->redirect($this->rewrite(DOMAIN_ROOT . $this->request->server['REQUEST_URI']));
    }
}
elseif (strpos($this->request->server['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') !== false) {
    $this->response->redirect(HTTPS_SERVER);
}
```

Add last step is to define `DOMAIN_ROOT` in `config.php` with

```php
define('DOMAIN_ROOT', 'https://www.somedomain.org'); // no slash, no subfolder
```

It works very well for me

Answer (score -1):

To remove `index.php?route=` from urls I simply recommend to edit `.htaccess` file.

Just add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?_route_=?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

I encounter no problems whatsoever. Just remember that you need to have **RewriteEngine** enabled. Look for this line: `RewriteEngine On`. If not present, past it before above code.

Comment: This does not remove it from the PHP files however that are hard coded to have this inside them.