# Rewrite all Home links in Opencart

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting, opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.4 that I have install in a /products subdirectory. I have a wordpress site installed in the root directory. I have skinned them the same so it looks like the same site.

I would like to rewrite all instances of Home links (especially the breadcrumbs) to go to my root directory (rather than the sub-directory (/products) where my OC install is at).

From some research I understand that the best way to do this is in the HTACCESS file. I am very unfamiliar with manipulating the htaccess file. The standard htaccess file has these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I add a rule to change the Home link from:

www.myurl.com/products/index.php?route=common/home

to:

www.myurl.com/

Finally, in the current install this file is called .htaccess.txt. Do I have to delete this file from the server, remove the .txt , and upload the file named .htaccess to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `index.php?route=common/home` follow the [guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart/10902883#10902883). As for the .htaccess code, you will need to upload that to your opencart install directory and remove the `.txt` from the name so that it becomes `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `http://www.myurl.com/` URL for both Wordpress and OpenCart since they both use index.php file. There's a work around you can use to make things look better:

You need a `.htaccess` file at your website root folder and in that `.htaccess` file add following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cart.php?route=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products/index.php?route=$1
```

This will make your OpenCart accessible from URL: `http://www.myurl.com/cart.php?route=common/home` instead of `www.myurl.com/products/index.php?route=common/home`

Answer (score 0):

You Setup is just like my setup, It's like this...

- Custom HTML in root - hxxp://mysite.loc/
- OpenCart in /store folder - hxxp://mysite.loc/store

I have a mod similar to what Jay Gilford mentioned in his answer. 

So my OC link is

http://mysite.loc/store

instead of

`http://mysite.loc/store/index.php?route=common/home`

With this setup, you will still find from the breadcrumbs path of any store links, the **Home** link. Like `Home > Category > Product`

In my case, what I did was, I've renamed the **Home** text to **Store** text. and had removed the **Home** Link Menu from the OC Menu. It's pretty simple, but practical I think.

I then added added my **Home** link to the breadcrumb trail and to my OC Menu. So my breadcrumb trail is like so...

`Home > Store> Category > Product`

**Home** link was hardcoded to every .tpl pages that contains the breadcrumb. Like the `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl`. You can further mod this by placing the breadcrumb to the header.

In my case, I've hard-coded this to  my 
`catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` and other related `.tpl` files

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <a href="/">Home</span></a>&raquo;
  <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
  <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I renamed the original `Home` link by doing this;

```
 changed
 $_['text_home']   = 'Home';

 to

 $_['text_home']   = 'Store';//Or whatever you like

 from the file. catalog/language/english.php - in my case.
```

**I know this was asked several months ago, Just posting this one for future readers**