# OpenCart on nginX

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, nginx, opencart

Can OpenCart use SEO URLs on nginX? I understand that in Apache, it creates an .htaccess, but is it capable of automatically managing the URL redirection in nginX?

Comment: What is stopping You from trying?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OpenCart on Nginx - We have been using it for a year. Finally it seems other people starting to use it. Getting help is a nightmare and getting in on Nginx is tricky sometimes..

My `www.site.com.vhost` is below, example:

```
# FORCE WWW
server {
    server_name  site.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.site.com$1 permanent;
}
# MAIN SERVER
# NINX 0.8.54 - WORKS ON 1.1.19
server {
    server_name  www.site.com;
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/www.site.com/web;
    index index.php index.html;
    location /image/data {
        autoindex on;
    }
    location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @opencart;
    }
    location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        deny all;
    }
    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

OK, now with regards to managing your site. You can now enable SEO via the admin, see my other posts [tagged nginx and opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:596952%20%5Bopencart%5D%20nginx) for all the URLs and further customisation with the `location /  {}`

I also recommend reading about removing the index.php?route= - link below:

[Remove index.php?route=common/home from OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart)

Comment: I would also be wary of the `audoindex on;` this is due to we use a CDN and it would be best to keep these folders private.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your setup more in detail. I tried using your config, but it does not seem to work at all. I am missing backgroud information about your FastCGI setup etc. etc.

Comment: Please post your own question @daemonfire300 as this setup does work. We use NGINX on all our OpenCart platform installs. `autoindex on` remove this, it is the equivalent of showing `index of / ` and listing all files...