# How can i remove index.php?route=common/home from OpenCart Version 1.5.1?

Tags: php, seo, opencart

I am currently using opencart version 1.5.1
SEO URL is set to "yes"

However for the homepage and a few other links; how do I remove?

index.php?route=common/home

Any opencart expertise can help me as soon as possible???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these posts will be helpful to you

1. http://www.nixstudio.com/seo-friendly-url-opencart/
2. http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=47149
3. [Remove index.php?route=common/home from OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart)