# OpenCart SEO index.php .htaccess redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart

I am trying to forward /index.php?route=common/home to the domain name itself.  I have tried the code below which works but it breaks the login page.  I think the issue is that they used the same url for /admin/index.php?route=common/home and it will not allow me to login to the admin center.  I have been unable to figure out how to fix the below redirect to restrict from the admin folder.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

```
# Redirect index to domain
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart

Comment: I was looking for a .htaccess fix not a php fix. If there is an update that effects the edited file you will have to edit it again.  Thus the reason for .htaccess redirects.

Comment: I understand, but the above will remove the common/home entirely. Also, you could write a very simlpe vQmod to do this for you so new versions don't overwrite the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your rule  with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?route=common/home[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```