# Opencart - Seo url for non-product pages

Tags: url, generics, methods, seo, opencart

Opencart module handles seo urls of product, category and information pages. Is there anyone knows the method for other pages.

For example : (special products page) http://www.pelinaksesuar.com/index.php?route=product/special

But we are looking for a generic method to change url like this /product/special
or /special-products

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are on 1.5.X - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7197

Comment: Follow this Tutorials for SEO URL: (Hope, helpfully for you.)
http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/09/12/how-to-turn-on-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/

Comment: The link given by @JayGilford is an extension available only for the previous version and the second seems to be a bad link now. Maybe check this thread about [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10813809/4094098). At this time, different solutions have been proposed, but mainly for the former version of OC (1.5.x and not 2.x).

Comment: @GizMecano after 18 months, I don't think this is still relevant

Comment: @JayGilford You are probably right. Maybe we need to open a new clean question to find the _best fit_ for setting correctly the SEO rewriting for this kind of links in OC 2.x (I must admit I still don't understand why this isn't a native feature).