# How to set Opencart URL category like this www.example.com/category/laptop

Tags: url, set, categories

How to set Opencart Ver 2.0.3.1 URL category like `www.example.com/mycategorykeyword/categoryname`?

I also set SEO URL in admin panel and also the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this thread about [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10813809/4094098). At this time, different solutions have been proposed, but mainly for the former version of OC (1.x and not 2.x).