# How to to shorten a URL using HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I have this kind of URL:

http://dev.myproject.local/index.php?route=product/category/feature

and I want to be like this:

http://dev.myproject.local/featurepage

I have this in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php?route=product/category/feature$ /featurepage/ [L]
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following solutions. I used similar last time.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?_route_=?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: I found another solution , may be it is worth to try if above solution does not work   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart