# OpenCart SEO URLs -> Links are not rewrited?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, seo, opencart

Fresh install of OpenCart, ive tried to enable URL Rewriting (SEO URLs) in the Admin Panel ..

I set up all my .htaccess correctly (but its obvious that this is not the problem)

Because : All links on the website ARE NOT REWRITED and still use $_GET['route'] value in it .. Example, the "My Account" link point to :

```
http://notjunk.ca/index.php?route=account/account
```

instead of

```
http://notjunk.ca/account/
```

(or something like this, i dunno im new to OpenCart)

I tried to clear the cache in system/cache/* but it doesnt works

How can I have URL without "index.php?route=XY" and instead, the $_GET['route'] contents is the URL itself (usually, like other CMS does) ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create custom SEO-friendly URLs in OpenCart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578055/how-can-i-create-custom-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not something that is available in OpenCart by default. Only the Products, Categories, Manufacturers and Information pages allow you to customise the urls through the use of their SEO Keyword field

However, there are commercial extensions available to do this such as [this one](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7197)