# Opencart custom url for login,register etc

Tags: opencart2.x

How to change the url of opencart from `index.php?route=account/login`  to **login** and

`index.php?route=account/register` to **register**

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578055/how-can-i-create-custom-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart

Comment: hi i needed for opencart latest version 2.0.1.1

Comment: where do u stuck.http://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/opencart2/seo-urls check this. always do google first

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin:

[SEO Complete plugin](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9486)

Answer (score 0):

go to admin panel --> setting--> Use SEO URLs - Yes. Rename .htaccess.txt file to .htaccess

apache module mod-rewrite must be installed on server

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the url by adding new rewrite rule 
ie: 
RewriteRule   ^login/?$    index.php?route=account/login  [L]  #login page

and add the link ie  www.example.com/login
like wise you can do it for the register 
my problem is solved by doing.