# opencart seo friendly url only works for some pages

Tags: php, url, seo, opencart

I'm working on my first project with opencart.
I activated seo friendly urls in setting. Some pages such as `about-us` are fine. but seo friendly urls don't work for checkout, cart, register,... pages. 
For example http://onelight.ir/about-us is ok, but http://onelight.ir/register shows an 404 page and I must use the long url. 
I checked my database. There's no record for register on `oc_url_alias` table but there's a row for `about-us` keyword, with value `information_id=4` for `query`.
I checked `catalog/controller/common` path. There's no `seo_url.php` file there if that helps.
my opencart version:  2.3.0.2

Thanks a lot for your time, and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: you can add a record to your `oc_url_alias` table with `account/register` as the query and `register` as the keyword. You'll need to update the links in your templates. Kind of a pain that there isn't an interface to add SEO URLs for some pages (much easier for products, manufacturers, information pages, etc)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot this is how it works:
I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578088/5571595) and [this link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-custom-urls-in-opencart--cms-25734). BUT `seo_url.php` file is in `catalog/controller/startup` directory.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.